# SQL Invalid Object Name 'AddressType'

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008, ssms, adventureworks

I am getting the above error in my VS 2008 C# method when I try to invoke the SQL getColumnNames stored procedure from VS.  This SP accepts one input parameter, the table name, and works successfully from SSMS.  Currently I am selecting the AdventureWorks AddressType table for it to pull the column names from this table.  I can see teh AdventureWorks table available in VS from my Server Explorer / Data Connection.  And I see both the AddressType table and getColumnNames SP showing in Server Explorer.

But I am still getting this error listed above.  Here is the C# code snippet I use to execute this:

public static DataTable DisplayTableColumns(string tt)
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        string TableName = tt;
        string connString = "Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks_Data.mdf\";Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False";
        string errorMsg;
        SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(connString);
        SqlCommand cmd = conn2.CreateCommand();

```
    try
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.getColumnNames";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Connection = conn2;
        SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@TableName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        parm.Value = TableName;
        parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
        conn2.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        errorMsg = ex.Message;
    }
```

And when I examine the errorMsg it says the following:

```
"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)\r\n
```

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()\r\n
at ADONET_namespace.ADONET_methods.DisplayTableColumns(String tt) in C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\AddFileToSQL\AddFileToSQL\ADONET methods.cs:line 35"

Where line 35 is

> dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly checked AdventureWorks database and see that the table "AddressType" belongs to the schema "Person". Try passing "Person.AddressType" as the value of the value of the command parameter in the code.

Comment: Great catch, Ashish!  This was the problem!